# If statement with multiple conditions using regex

Tags: python, if-statement

I would like to loop through pull requests in GitHub and if the pull request has the comments in the code below, do something (for now, print the pull request number).  I have a pull request that has the comments I'm looking for (spread over multiple comments in the pull request), but it doesn't print the pull request number.  I suspect it has something to do with the regex I'm using because if I break the if statement down to look for just the regex or the string values, it works fine, but when I try to combine them in one if statement, it doesn't work.

I don't think this is a duplicate question as I've looked at all the suggestions under questions that may already have your answer.

```
    for pr in repo.pull_requests():
        #check to ensure pull request meets criteria before processing
        conflicts_base_branch = "This branch has no conflicts with the base branch"
        checks = "All checks have passed"
        sign_off_comment_present = re.compile(r"\B#sign-off\b", re.IGNORECASE)
        for comment in list(repo.issue(pr.number).comments()):
            if (conflicts_base_branch and checks in comment.body) and (sign_off_comment_present.search(comment.body)):
                print(pr.number)
```

Comment: Are all of these present in _one_ comment or in different comments? Your version requires them to be all in the _same_ comment. Also `conflicts_base_branch and checks in comment.body` is the same as `(conflicts_base_branch) and (checks in comment.body)` or `(True) and (checks in comment.body)`, so it only checks for the presence of the latter.

Comment: These are present in multiple comments in the pull request.  Does this mean it should be `if conflicts_base_branch in comment.body and checks in comment.body`? If so, how do I combine that with the regex statement?

Comment: You need to check them separately while iterating. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution requires all of the conditions to be met on the *same* comment, it won't work if they are on different comments. For that you need to keep track which conditions are met while iterating through the comments, e.g:

```
for pr in repo.pull_requests():
    #check to ensure pull request meets criteria before processing
    conflicts_base_branch = "This branch has no conflicts with the base branch"
    checks = "All checks have passed"
    sign_off_comment_present = re.compile(r"\B#sign-off\b", re.IGNORECASE)
    passes_checks = False
    has_signoff = False
    has_no_conflicts = False
    for comment in list(repo.issue(pr.number).comments()):
        if checks in comment.body:
            passes_checks = True
        if conflicts_base_branch in comment.body:
            has_no_conflicts = True
        if sign_off_comment_present.search(comment.body):
            has_signoff = True
    if passes_checks and has_no_conflicts and has_signoff:
        print(pr.number)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked!  I forget about checking each condition separately while going through the pull request comments.